# Windows Phone Application - Start page depends on FileExist in isolated storage

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm developing application that start page depends on file existing in isolated storage.
If file doesn't exist my application shows some form to setup configuration, but if it exist I wish this page will not be diesplayed.

For now I just load configutarion page but if file exist i use NavigationService to navigate to proper page on pageloaded event. The problem is that after I play with my app and hit back button it goes to configuration setup and because file exist it navigates me stright to my app again. I despite the fact that setup screen blinks on the application launching.

So my question is - how to setup startup page depends on some condition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to launch different page on some conditions.

There are methods to manipulate Page Stack in NavigationService class, so you can remove setup page from history and app not will be navigated to it when user tap back button.

For fighting with page blinking you can put an image (the same image as splashscreen) above your page, and hide it when right content loaded

Comment: actually in backstack there's no method called "remove" or "delete" and it's readonly so I cannot assign it without setup page...

Comment: You can use the NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry method to remove the most recent journal entry from the back history.

Answer (score 3):

The advice that I've heard is to use a UserControl on your startup page - then toggle the visibility depending on the condition you have.  That way you don't end up with an unwanted page in the backstack and you get to fully control the UX.

The example I heard it with was a login page - not something you want on the backstack usually - but something you can easily check a bool to hide/show the user control.

The place I heard it was this video from Mix 11: [Expert Lessons: Top Tips for Building a Successful Windows Phone Application](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/DVC04).  You can download the code to the demo (it is the first demo in that video) from the bottom of his blog entry here (which gives some more detail): [Demos from my Mix 2011 session - Part 1: Navigation Tips](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/swick/archive/2011/04/18/demos-from-my-mix-2011-session-part-1-navigation-amp-phone-states.aspx)

Comment: have you maybe a link with tutorial?

Comment: I just added the links to the answer above to the video and blog entry with the code download that you need.